# ajax call not working in phone gap, how to?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

i have a function that changes the page:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    if (data  == 1 ) {
           $.mobile.changePage( "second.html", { transition: "slideup"} );
   } else {
        showConfirm();
   }
}, 
...
```

on `second.html` i have a ajax call that loads some data from a php file.

if i go to `second.html` i get the results but not if i get there by using the `$.mobile.changePage...`

any idea what needs to be done? does something need to be initialized again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of jQuery Mobile. The changepage event doesn't:

- load the whole page
- execute any javascript that may be on the new page

It just dumps the loaded html inside a new div on the current page.

Move all your javascript from second.html to the index page inside a pageshow event and that *should* do the trick.

Hope this helps.